# Grails nullable:true not working after modifying domain class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, grails

I have a domain class with few fields. The application was running and then I had to add 2 more fields to the domain class which were marked as nullable:

```
class SomeDomain{
   // Fields from beginning
   .............
   // Two fields added afterwards
   String fieldA
   String fieldB
   static constraints = {
     // Constraints on initial fields
     ...............
     // Constraints on fields added afterwards
     fieldA(nullable: true)
     fieldB(nullable: true)
   }

}
```

But when I run this, then I see the fields added to mysql table. But they don't have the nullable constraint. So its not allowing nulls in those fields. What could be the reason and is there any way to solve this. Obviously I can edit the mysql tables directly to add the Nullable property to those two fields. However I want to know why it create the two fields in the table, but failed to add the null constraint(so that in future I can avoid such errors).

I am using Grails 2.2.1.

Comment: Did you already have data in your table when you changed the constraints? You can avoid a lot of these types of issues by using database migrations and not relying on the automatic features of GORM.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore yes I had data in the table. Actually I don't have database migration plugin in my application. So do you recommend adding database migration plugin? Whats the recommended standard approach to follow for making changes to database later on after data is added?(apart from manually writing sql to database directly)

Comment: It's very common to use the database migration plugin to manage these changes. It's so common that the plugin has become part of the core of Grails in later versions. I'd highly recommend you use it and avoid any future pitfalls, since it automates a lot for you and still gives you easy manual control.