# update domain column with nullable:true

Tags: mysql, grails

Using `grails 2.2.5` & `mySql` & `database-migration:1.3.2` which is mentioned in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178945/grails-nullabletrue-not-working-after-modifying-domain-class) setting column `deleted nullable:true` doesn't change the value into DB

At first I added the deleted property `Boolean deleted` without  the `deleted nullable:true` so when I started the app into my DB I have Null : **Non** (which is **No** in French)

Then I have added `deleted nullable:true` but when I re-run the app nothing changed, I still have `Null : Non` (last line on the picture)

do I have to change it manually ?

[image]

The domain

```
class Comment {

    Date dateCreated
    Boolean deleted
    String comment;
    Boolean rootComment;
    int vote;

    static belongsTo = [contributor: Contributor, discussion: Discussion]
    static hasOne = [project: Project]
    static mapping = {
        autoTimestamp true
        deleted defaultValue: "0"
        deleted nullable:true
    }
}
```

Note that into Datasource.groovy I have `dbCreate = "update"`

```
    dataSource {
        pooled = true
        dbCreate = "update" // UPDATE
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/soundsharedb"
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        username = "xxx"
        password = "xxx"
        logSql = false
        properties {
            stOnBorrow = true
            testWhileIdle = true
            testOnReturn = true
            validationQuery = 'SELECT 1'
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a database migration to alter the nullable flag for that column. We use migrations for ALL our database operations -- creating/modifying/removing tables, columns, indices, the whole lot.

For the change you want to implement, a discrete step might be something akin to:

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    changeSet(author: "You", id: "some unique ID") {
        dropNotNullConstraint(columnDataType: "bit", columnName: "deleted", tableName: "comment") 
    }
}
```

Read up on the database-migration plugin for how to generate/write migrations and use them for programmatic database changes.

Comment: Well I have a lot of problems using database migration but your answer satisfy me. Thank you